# Manage API from Cloud Shell Editor

Tags: service, gcloud, alpha, undelete

I try to manage API keys from Cloud Shell Editor to restore an API (autocreated by Firebase) that I deleted.

I try to run `gcloud alpha services api-keys undelete BYuihiuYUIGyugIIHU...` but i receive Error: **ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.services.api-keys.undelete) NOT_FOUND: Method not found.**

I try to run (for testing) `gcloud alpha services api-keys list` command but I receive error: **ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.services.api-keys.list) Projects instance [PROJECT_ID] not found: Method not found.**

What I'm wrong?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

thank you so much for answer.
The result of commands is:

version -->

```
Google Cloud SDK 327.0.0
alpha 2021.02.05
beta 2021.02.05
bq 2.0.64
core 2021.02.05
gsutil 4.58
kpt 0.37.1
minikube 1.17.1
skaffold 1.19.0
```

Component list -->

```
Installed        │ gcloud Alpha Commands                                │ alpha                    │  < 1 MiB
```

I tried to remove and reinstall gcloud-sdk with:
`sudo apt purge --autoremove google-cloud-sdk`
and `sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk` but nothing has changed

Comment: And, what happens if you type `gcloud alpha services`?

Comment: `gcloud alpha services` --> `ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.services) Command name argument expected.`
`gcloud alpha services api-keys` --> `ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.services.api-keys) Command name argument expected.`
`gcloud alpha services api-keys list` --> Ask me to autorize and after `ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.services.api-keys.list) Projects instance [PROJECT_ID] not found: Method not found.`

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that (for some reason), your Cloud Shell is not running the latest version of `gcloud` (Cloud SDK). The latest version is `328.0.0`. My Cloud Shell is running `327.0.0` includes the alpha commands (see below) and the commands work for me.

What is the result of the following in Cloud Shell?

- `gcloud version`
- `gcloud components list` does the list include `gcloud Alpha Commands`?

I'm confident that `gcloud Alpha Commands` are installed (by default) on Cloud Shell and so suspect that, for some reason, you're running an outdated version of Cloud SDK.

I'm unsure how you can install `gcloud Alpha Commands` under Cloud Shell if the component isn't installed because using `gcloud commands` will error under Cloud Shell but it should (!) tell you which `apt-get install` command you will need:

```sh
gcloud components install alpha
```

I assumed it was not permitted (since Cloud Shell is managed) but it is possible to self-update Cloud SDK in Cloud Shell. The following update will again tell you that you can't run the command in Cloud Shell but, it should give you a set of `apt-get install` commands that you can use to perform the update:

```sh
gcloud components update
```

Here's a link to the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes) for Cloud SDK. It's not obvious from these notes when these methods were added.

Comment: Hopefully it helped?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I posted my situation as an answer to make it readable.